# f1() function is not being called if the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.f1 = function(){

$scope.half = $scope.pany.length / 2;
if($scope.ctrack < $scope.half){
            document.getElementById(buttonid).style.color = "green";
}
        else
        {
            alert("You have no more letters to flip, please make your guess NOW!");
            $scope.wanna();
        }   
        $scope.ctrack++;
}


$scope.f2=function(){
    alert("There is nothing in this box.");         
}

$scope.game = function(){

    while($scope.boxcount<=99)
    {   
        if($scope.boxcount==50){
            $scope.tab = $scope.tab + "</tr><tr>";   
        }
        if($scope.boxcount < $scope.size)
        {   
                $scope.tab = $scope.tab + "<td><button class='c1' id='"+$scope.boxcount+"' ng-click='f1("+"'"+$scope.boxcount+"'"+")';>"+$scope.pany.charAt($scope.boxcount)+"</button></td>";

        }
        else
        {
            $scope.tab = $scope.tab + "<td><button class='c2' id='"+$scope.boxcount+"' ng-click='f2();' ></button></td>";
        }
        $scope.boxcount++;
    }   
        $scope.tab = $scope.tab + "</table>";
        document.getElementById('tabcells').innerHTML = $scope.tab;
}
```

The execution of f1() function is not happening if the button is clicked

Comment: Please note the tags in your question. This question is about angularjs, not angular :)

Comment: @Harshini Have you written `<button ng-click="f1();"></button>` in html.

Comment: because you added elements to view after load angularjs, you must use model and ng-repeat to add element

Comment: @MerajKhan As i see it genarete by code in :`$scope.game = function(){`

Comment: from where you are calling that function please specify?

Comment: use $scope.$compile() after add elements to view

Comment: @Harshini You didn't close controller function properly last line `)};` is missing.

Comment: please show your html code especially the button